# How to add post classes?

Tags: php, post-class

I can use [`post_class()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_class/) to echo all classes for a post. How can I output only the `category-ID` as a class, and how can I include this while using [`heredoc string syntax`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)?

I got this function in which I would like to use `post_class()`, and I have tried `get_post_class()` which does not work, because its an array to string conversion.

```
function imageHolder($ID) {
    $classes = get_post_class($ID, 'image-holder');
    return <<<HTML
        <div $classes></div>
HTML;
}

echo imageHolder(2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function imageHolder($id){
    $category  = get_the_category($id);
    $class = '"category-' . strtolower($category[0]->cat_name) . '"';
    print <<<HTML
    <div class=$class>
       This is a Test
    </div>
    HTML;
}
imageHolder('1');
```

Please be careful about using '/n' or '/r' symbol in the Heredoc syntax(they might cause the function does not work properly).

Comment: is there a reason for you to change `return <<<` to `print <<<` in some way of best practice methods? Thanks for this great work-around!

Comment: Hi Marian, the return <<< is also gonna works. But you will need to echo your function. They are pretty much the same, in my opinion. Therefore there is no specific reason why did I change the return <<< to print <<<. I am glad I helped you out with this.